# WMI Lookup Values

Tags: c#, wmi

I"m using WMI to retrieve information for a server's operating system. I have the following the query ->

```
select *  from Win32_OperatingSystem
```

The results are fine, however for the OperatingSystemSKU, it returns an integer. On the microsoft website it provides the actual value. I was wondering if this look-up table exists or will I have to create my own local table to do the mapping?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394239(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: What about the Caption property? It seems to contain that information in a localized string.

Answer (score 1):

You can look it up like this

```
string OSname = (from x in new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem").Get().OfType<ManagementObject>() select x.GetPropertyValue("Caption")).First().ToString();
```

Or just use a messagebox.

```
MessageBox.Show((from x in new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem").Get().OfType<ManagementObject>() select x.GetPropertyValue("Caption")).First().ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the valid values for the `OperatingSystemSKU` property accessing the `Values` qualifier.

Check the next image (obtained using [WDCC](http://code.google.com/p/wmi-delphi-code-creator/)) which shows all the qualifiers and values for the  `OperatingSystemSKU` property.

[image]

From .Net you must use the [QualifierData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.qualifierdata%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) Class to extract such info.

Check the next  C# sample which build a Lookup list using the Qualifier values.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Management;
using System.Text;

namespace GetWMI_Info
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                List<string> sLookUp = new List<string>();
                ManagementClass manClass = new ManagementClass("Win32_OperatingSystem");
                manClass.Options.UseAmendedQualifiers = true;
                foreach (PropertyData Property in manClass.Properties)
                    if (Property.Name.Equals("OperatingSystemSKU"))                    
                        foreach (QualifierData Qualifier in Property.Qualifiers)
                            if (Qualifier.Name.Equals("Values")) 
                                foreach (String s in (System.String[])Qualifier.Value)
                            sLookUp.Add(s);                   


                ManagementScope Scope;                
                Scope = new ManagementScope(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\CIMV2", "."), null);
                Scope.Connect();
                ObjectQuery Query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT OperatingSystemSKU FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");
                ManagementObjectSearcher Searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(Scope, Query);

                foreach (ManagementObject WmiObject in Searcher.Get())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", "OperatingSystemSKU", sLookUp[Convert.ToInt32((UInt32)WmiObject["OperatingSystemSKU"])]);// Uint32
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Exception {0} Trace {1}",e.Message,e.StackTrace));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a (very trimmed) method I wrote a while ago - gets the name and also gets the windows version as a string using Environment.OSVersion - I'm just assuming you want the OS version name here rather than the sku?

```
/// <summary>
/// Class for getting environment information
/// </summary>
public static class EnvironmentInfo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets environment information by querying the system
    /// </summary>
    public static IEnumerable<string> GetEnvironmentInfo()
    {
        List<string> results = new List<string>();

        SafeUpdateListOfResultsFromInstrumentation("OS Product: {0}", results, "select * from win32_OperatingSystem", "name");
        SafeUpdateListofResults("OS Version: {0}", results, (() => Environment.OSVersion.ToString()));

        return results;
    }

    private static void SafeUpdateListofResults(string format, List<string> results, Func<string> del)
    {
        try
        {
            string str = del.Invoke();
            results.Add(string.Format(format, str));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //Swallow exception - can't get diagnostic info!
        }
    }

    private static void SafeUpdateListOfResultsFromInstrumentation(string format, List<string> results, string query, string index)
    {
        try
        {
            WqlObjectQuery objectQuery = new WqlObjectQuery(query);
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(objectQuery);

            string name, value;

            foreach (ManagementObject managementObject in searcher.Get())
            {
                name = managementObject[index].ToString();
                string[] split1 = name.Split('|');
                value = split1[0];
                results.Add(string.Format(format, value));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //Swallow exception - can't get diagnostic info!
        }

    }
}
```